# Reading a variable directly from file

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to, get a variable from another PHP file and assign it directly to a variable?

Eg. -

File 1 - users.php

```
<?php

[
    "name" => "John",
    "age" => 34
]

?>
```

File 2 - accounts.php

```
<?php

$user = get_var_from_file(users.php);

?>
```

get_var_from_file is the function that takes the array from  users.php and assigns it directly and assigns it to `$users`.

#### Why do I want do this?

My goal here is to make the users.php file as simple as possible, because it's going to be accessed by non technical people.

Comment: That approach feels very unsuitable for non technical people.

Comment: Why not just use a CSV?

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: I reached a compromise :) .

Answer (score 1):

Make the file a JSON file (remove the PHP tags) and then use `file_get_contents(user.json)` and then parse the JSON with `json_decode()`. There will be no need to reassign to other variables, just use the array identifiers from the decoding process.

Comment: I think you may need to remove the php tags from the file for this to work `<?php ?>`.  Also, I suggest changing the file extension to .json for the users.php file.

Comment: Yes my file is a PHP file.. Cant use json_decode() I think.

Answer (score 0):

simply return the variable you want to return :

```
<?php

return [
    "name" => "John",
    "age" => 34
]

?>
```

and in another file:

```
$users = include 'users.php';
```

Comment: Any way to do without `return`? I want just an array in the file.

Comment: @Haris You are able to add that `return` through the other file without manually editing it.

Comment: well, there's always `json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'))` which is prety much a standard and can work way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `require` keyword

**file users.php**

```
$users = [
  'name' => 'John',
  'age' => 34
];
```

**file accounts.php**

```
require('users.php');
$age = $users['age'];
echo $age;
// should return 34
```

Comment: Dont wan't to write `$users = `. Possible without that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the JSON approach, failing that I would use the CSV approach, failing that maybe [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).  However, to answer the specific format you show, just `eval` it:

```
function get_var_from_file($file) {
    $array = file_get_contents($file);
    eval("\$result = $array;");
    return $result;
}
```

JSON is easy, so is the INI and the CSV can be easy:

```
$result = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

Comment: eval + unverified input, what could _possibly_ go wrong :)

Comment: I know right, but why verify they are _non technical people_ ;-)